# Espresso machine has to warm up halfway through pulling a shot

Tags: coffee, espresso

I've had my espresso machine for a little less than a year. It's a DeLonghi EC155. It heats up fine (I assume so - a green light that means "ready" turns on, and I've followed the instructions and let it sit for 30 minutes heating before using it), but when I pull a shot, it makes the sound of the water being pushed through the grounds, but the green light turns off halfway through the process. I stop pulling the shot, wait for the light to come on, and finish pulling the shot.

Usually when I dispose of the grounds, they're very watery. Is there a way to make the machine hold heat longer, or is it a defect with the machine?

EDIT: It should also be noted that the light turning off halfway through is a relatively new occurrence. Before about a month ago the "ready" light would stay on until after I had pulled my shot.

Comment: Have you tried just leaving it to do it's thing? You mention stopping mid pull...

Comment: I haven't, because I'm afraid the light turning off will produce a lukewarm espresso. I'll pull a shot in one go tomorrow and report how it went.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you stop in the middle ? Is there a drop in pressure ? does the coffee continue dripping down in the cup?

Let it finish.

I assume, if it is working like my machine, that the water is being re-heated for a next shot.

1st thing I would do is to clean the machine with a "descaler"; it should help with the water heating system and the pressure.

If that does not help, have the machine looked at.

Comment: +1 for descale. Definitely sounds like limescale build-up to me.

Comment: If you haven't descaled yet - better hurry before the machine is damaged. 
I would also suggest cleaning the metal coffee filter.

Comment: +1. I have a similar DeLonghi (EC702) and the fact of the matter is that cheaper espresso machines like these just have tiny boilers. Just the act of pulling one shot can cause the boiler temp to drop, the thermostat to trigger, and the "ready" light to turn off. But Max is right...scaling will exacerbate this even further.

Answer (score -2):

Home espresso machines in that price range are hopeless. Especially if you want to steam milk. They are not powerful enough. You've been sold a $200 lie. La Marzocco is making two home machines but are for the high end market at 20-40 times the price of your machine. Really high end. You're likely better off going the Italian home coffee way and buying a Moka Pot. Or better yet, try your local cafe.

Comment: Not everyone can or want to spend money on an expensive coffee machine; either they are not into coffee like some others are or find that it works well enough for them (my case); I've been using a Breville espresso machine for a couple of years now and it works nicely and steam milk the way I like.

Comment: I think this is an answer to the question, in that it's claiming that yes, the OP's machine is defective and further so are all machines in that price range. Not sure it's a useful or correct answer, though.